# Any field change in form, disable button, and activate another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JavaScript code that activates a button and deactivates another if a select is changed.

**HTML**

```
<select name="list" id="list">
     <option value="">choose</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="1">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>                
</select>
<input name="refresh" type="button" value="refresh" disabled="" />
<input name="add" type="button" value="add"  />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var op = $(this).val();
    if (op != '') {
        $('input[name="refresh"]').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('input[name="refresh"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
$('select').change(function () {
    var op = $(this).val();
    if (op != '') {
        $('input[name="add"]').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('input[name="add"]').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

I need to expand the function to all fields in the form with minimal code. I could use the same code for the rest of inputs, but the code will be very long. I'm looking for a short version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Targetting elements

`$('select')` is generic selector and will select all `<select>` elements on the page. There might be some `<select>` elements which are not needed to target for this functionality.

You can target only required elements using

1. Unique parent selector + descendant selector

   In this, there will be a main *container* element and using this all the descendant `<select>` elements can be targeted.

   Example:

   **HTML:**

   ```
   <div id="container">
       <select name="list" id="list">
           <option value="">...</option>
       </select>
       <input name="refresh" />
       <input name="add" type="button" value="add" />

       <select name="list1" id="list1">
           <option value="">...</option>
       </select>
       <input name="refresh1" />
       <input name="add1" type="button" value="add1" />

       ...
   </div>
   ```

   **JavaScript:**

   ```
   $('#container select').change(function() {
   ```
2. Using common class
   Sometimes, adding all the elements under a container is not possible. In such cases, adding a common class to all the elements will allow to select elements using class selector.

   ```
   $('.someCommonClass').change(function() {
   ```

   Common attributes can also be added and selected using [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). However, this can be slower than class selectors.

Similarly, another common + unique class should be applied to buttons.

```
<input name="refresh" class="anotherUnique" />
<input name="add" class="anotherUnique" />
```

Then, to disable/enable these buttons, they can be referenced.

### HTML5 `data-*` attributes

HTML5's custom [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attribute can be used to store custom data on HTML elements.

```
<select name="list" id="list" data-key="value">
```

### Getting `data-*` attribute value

jQuery provides [`data(name)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) method to get the value of the `data-name` attribute value. Core JavaScript has [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property that allows access to data attributes.

```
$('elemSelector').data('key')
```

### Using `prop()` with value

[`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) accepts second parameter which will be converted to Boolean internally and depending on the value, the action will be taken. So, the `if` and `else` statements in the question can be combined as

```
$('elemSelector').prop('disabled', booleanValueHere);
```

If second parameter is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy), element will be disabled. If [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) then element will be enabled.

### Putting it all together

```js
// Bind change event on all select elements
// having unique class
$('select.unique').change(function () {
    // Cache this
    var $this = $(this);

    // Get the data-* attribute values
    var button1 = $this.data('button1'),
        button2 = $this.data('button2');

    // Get the value of this select box
    // Use this as second parameter to prop
    $('input[name="' + button1 + '"]').prop('disabled', this.value);
    $('input[name="' + button2 + '"]').prop('disabled', !this.value);
});
```

```css
/* For Demo Purpose */
input {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
input:disabled {
  color: gray;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="list" id="list" class="unique" data-button1="refresh" data-button2="add">
    <option value="">choose</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input name="refresh" type="button" class="anotherUnique" value="Refresh" />
<input name="add" type="button" class="anotherUnique" value="Add" disabled />

<hr />
<!-- Another select box -->
<select name="list1" id="list1" class="unique" data-button1="refresh1" data-button2="add1">
    <option value="">choose</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
<input name="refresh1" type="button" class="anotherUnique1" value="Refresh 1" />
<input name="add1" type="button" class="anotherUnique1" value="Add 1" disabled />
```

### Conclusion

Now, the JavaScript code don't have to be written again for each new `select` element. Just adding the markup with required attributes will automatically work. The relation between *HTML element-JavaScript handler* is reduced from many to many to many to one.

Comment: Hello Tushar! Nice to see you!

Comment: @Yvette Welcome to CR!